# Endomorphism of a CM elliptic curve E can always be defined over its CM field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve which has CM in an imaginary quadratic field $K$ and let $\tau$ denote the element of $K$ for which $End(E)=\mathbb{Z}[\tau]$. How can one prove that the action of $\tau$ on $E(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$ is given by $(x,y) \to (\phi(x,y),\psi(x,y))$, where $\phi(x,y), \psi(x,y) \in K(X,Y)$ are rational functions defined over $K$? I am interested in the proof of the fact that the rational functions are defined over $K$, rather than that the isogeny is given by rational functions. Also, can one say something more precise than that about $\phi(x,y), \psi(x,y)$?

Comment: Can you give, please, a non-trivial example of  $(\phi(x,y), \psi(x,y)) \in K(X,Y)$ in $E(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$? If you give me what I asked then I shall can answer I guess. Thanks.

Comment: Consider $E:y^2=x^3-x$. Then the action of the endomorphism [i] on a point $(x,y)$ is given by $[i](x,y)=(-x,iy)$, so in this case $\phi(x,y)=-x$ and $\psi(x,y)=-iy$. The given elliptic curve has complex multiplication in $K=\mathbb{Q}(i)$ so the result is true in this case.

Comment: Thanks, F. Holz, for your answer. In truth I was asking about something else. Please, answer now 

(1) Do you consider $(\sqrt3 x ^ 2-yi, - \sqrt [3] {x-7})$ as rational or non-rational over your $ K $? (the second question (2) in other comment).

Comment: (2) Are you sure that $ [i] (x, y) = (- x, iy)$? For example, the curves $x^3 +y^3 = Az^3$ ($ A $ cube-free), birationally equivalent to the Weiestrass cubic $ y ^ 2z = x ^ 3-432A ^ 2z ^ 3 $ admit complex multiplication by $\sqrt{-3}$ and $$[\sqrt{-3}](x,y,z)=(3Az^3+\sqrt{-3}(x^3-y^3),3Az^3-\sqrt{-3}(x^3-y^3),6xyz)$$ which defines an isogeny of degree 3.  What degree corresponds to the CM by $i$?

Comment: By rational function in $K(X,Y)$ I mean an expression of the form $P(X,Y)/Q(X,Y$), where $P,Q \in K[X,Y]$ are two polynomials in $X$ and $Y$. Since $\sqrt{3} \not\in \mathbb{Q}(i)$, in your example of (1), what you wrote is not a rational function defined over $ \mathbb{Q}(i)$. For (2), the answer is yes, and $[i] \circ [i]=[-1]$.

Comment: Thank you. And the degree of $[i]$? The degree of $P\to 2P$ is $4$ and the degree of $P\to nP$ is $n^2$ What would be the degree of $[i]$ composed with itself $4n$ times if $[i] \circ [i]=[-1]$. Very cordially. Greetings.

Comment: See Theorem 2.2 in "Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves" of J. H. Silveman. The proof relies on some computations with invariant differentials.
Spoiler: if E is defined over $L$ then every endomorphism is defined over $KL$. I found this MSE question while looking for a proof that a CM morphism is not defined over $\mathbb Q$. I guess that this can also be proved with a similar method using invariant differentials.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.- What made me doubt a bit was your writing "....that the action of $\tau$ on $E(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$ is given by $(x,y) \to (\phi(x,y),\psi(x,y))$".

Now I know that your $(x,y)$ is an element of $E$ and therefore your question is almost trivial since $E$ is an abelian group (whose addition is rational) and the operation involved is that of the group itself so it can not give results outside the group. If you put the equation of $E$ in its homogeneous form, all operation in $E$ gives an element of $E$ whose three coordinates are polynomials so that returning to the afinne form  you have rational functions in $K(X,Y)$ (when dividing by $Z$; see the given example with $x^3+y^3=Az^3$ ) to coefficients in your field $K$. I suggest you very cordially delete your post by not relevant (I will not be the one to put a vote to "close" because I do not like to object to the posters). Regards.
$$*******$$

Hello Holz. I try to answer your comment before deleting mine. The ring $ \ End (E)$ is either isomorphe to $\mathbb Z$ (when $E$ is not with CM) or a subring of the ring of integers of an imaginary quadratic field (when $E$ is with CM).

Very briefly, the endomorphisms of the torus $\mathbb C/L$ (the  plane modulo the lattice L giving the elliptic curve $E$) are determined by the  numbers $\alpha$ such that $\alpha L\subseteq L$ and it happens that sometimes there are non-rational $\alpha$ (necessarily imaginary quadratic) fulfilling this condition.

In the case of $x^3+y^3=Az^3$, the ring of integers of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-3}$), because of $-3\equiv1\pmod4$, is
$$A=\dfrac 12(a+b\sqrt{-3})\text { with } a,b\in\mathbb Z$$ so $\ End (E)$ shoul be a subring of $A$. In particular, for $(a,b)=(0,2)$, you have that $[\sqrt{-3}]$ is an endomorfism of $E$ and every allowed operation with it or in conjunction with himself or others give necessarily rational function over $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-3})$ by the rational definition of the group law in $E$.

Comment: I am not sure if we talk about the same thing, so l will write a concrete example and hopefully you can help me clarify it. Let $E$ be an elliptic curve which is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ and has complex multiplication in $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$. Let $\tau \in K$ be an element such that $End(E) \cong \mathbb{Z}[\tau]$. How do you know that the action of $\tau$ on $E$ can be defined over $K$?

Comment: I answer you in editing. Regards. I don't discard that you are looking for anything else, maybe.

Comment: Thank you very much for this :)

Comment: You are welcome.